# Gnuplot and C "x range is invalid"

Tags: c, gnuplot

I'm trying to generate a data file and to plot it with Gnuplot. The problem is when I keep my Nstep lower than 348 I get the error

> ```
> line 0: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
>
> plot 'plot.txt' using 1:2 with lines
>                                     ^
> line 0: x range is invalid
> ```

But I keep the `Nstep` higher than 348 everything works fine. I do not understand why. Here is my C code:

```
int main(void){

    int Nstep = 348;

    //omitted part...

    FILE *pipe = fopen("plot.txt", "w+");

    while (n<Nstep) {
        pos[n+1] = pos[n] + v[n]*h;
        v[n+1] =  v[n] + h * Fx(pos[n]);

        fprintf(pipe, "%d %05.3lf\n", n, v[n]);
        n++;
        } 

    close(pipe);

    system("gnuplot -p -e \"plot 'plot.txt' using 1:2 with lines\"");

    return 0;    
}
```

plot.txt example (Nstep = 10)

```
1 100.000
2 99.000
3 97.000
4 94.010
5 90.050
6 85.150
7 79.349
8 72.697
9 65.252
10 57.079
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to replicate your error as you didn't include the full source (function `Fx` and definitions of `pos` and `v`). You are calling the wrong close. You should call `fclose()` (this will flush the file handle too).

```
fclose(pipe)
```

And not

```
close(pipe)
```

You could explicitly flush the data by calling `fflush()`.